# Error al intentar instalar un programa en Ubuntu, no carga ni nada

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Estoy intentando instalar Xampp en Ubuntu pero no me deja, tengo el programa descargado en la carpeta Descargas.

Instrucciones en la terminal:

```
erick@erick-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ cd Descargas/

erick@erick-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/Descargas$ sudo ./xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run

[sudo] contraseña para erick: 

erick@erick-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/Descargas$
```

No hace mas nada. No entiendo.

Comment: Dale permisos de ejecución: `chmod +x xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run`

Comment: Lo hice y nada.